# Querying fusion table columns with slider, FusionTableLayer

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, uislider

I'm trying to create slider for fusion table layers. My problem is how to set slider to query different columns in one FusinTable. For now I can slide between data in one column. I need to slide between different years 2004-2009 and each year data is in different column named same as year.

```
// define the JQuery Slider
$(function() {
    $('#slider').slider({
        max: 13000000,
        min: 1000000,
        step: 100000,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            document.getElementById("slider-value").innerHTML = ui.value + " Population (Thousends)";
            layer_0.setOptions({
                query: {
                    select: "Population",
                    from: "1ExY2P7DxDzTwjz67cs1GPgWKWDPUx5mXE3uZ2ME",
                    where: "Population <= " +  ui.value
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the 2 sliders(1 for the population and 1 for the year). Lets assume the sliders have the IDs `slider_population` and `slider_year`.

Create a single function to handle the update of the Layer:

```
function setQuery(){

  var population  =$( '#slider_population').slider( "option", "value" );
  var year        =$( '#slider_year').slider( "option", "value" );
  var query={
                select: "City",
                from: "tableId",
                where: "'"+ year +"' <= " +  population
            }
  layer_0.setOptions({query:query})

}
```

Inside the `slide`-callback of both sliders call this function(with a short delay, it takes a moment until jquery may recognize the correct value for the active slider):

```
       slide: function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout(setQuery,100);

        //more code
       }
```